# Logical OR operator result as rvalue

Tags: c++, language-agnostic, logic

This code I found while doing code review. Is there any hidden problem in this code or is it just fine?

```
myBool = myBoolA || ( oldState == AS_PLAYING );   //code #1
```

**Edit:** One typing mistake (`myBoolA` in place of `myBool`) by me created some nasty confusion; I am really sorry for that.

Actually the code to be reviewed is :

```
myBool = myBool || ( oldState == AS_PLAYING );   //code #1, not myBoolA
```

and my suggested code is:

```
if( oldState == AS_PLAYING ) myBool = true;   //code #2
```

Advantages with code#2 IMO :

1. better readability
2. if `myBool` is unintialized to begin with, there won't be Undefined behaviour.

Comment: Your suggestion as is doesn't have the same meaning. You completely left out `myBoolA`

Comment: The two lines you show are not equivalent.

Comment: Well second version doesn't use `myBoolA`, but it's most likely good advice to not try and stick everything on one line.

Comment: And no there's no problem with the first line you show. Do *you* have a problem with it? Does it produce unexpected results? What is your *actual* problem?

Comment: Your updated suggestion still ignores `myBoolA` and is *not* equivalent.

Comment: initialize myBool with true with that, Code#2 will be fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`myBool = myBoolA || ( oldState == AS_PLAYING );` is absolutely fine.

`||` is a sequencing point in C++, so even if the expression on the right hand side depends on the left hand side (perhaps `oldState` is a *reference* to `myBool` or `myBoolA`), the behaviour will be defined.

Your recommendation in changing this to

`if( oldState == AS_PLAYING )  myBool = true;`

is actually functionally different (the assignment to `myBool` is different for example), so don't change it to that.

Finally, note that the short-circuiting nature of `||` is obviated if `||` is overloaded. So always check that when refactoring code.

Comment: +1 for a actually answering the question instead of just pointing out the mistake. This should be the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks. In hurry, I mis-typed `myBool` as `myBoolA`.

Comment: @SauravSahu - Also note. That if `oldState == AS_PLAYING` was in fact a more expansive check, your suggestion will *always* preform it. While the original code will skip it when it isn't required.

Answer (score 1):

As per your comments later,

You can refactor as follows:

```
if(!myBool)
    myBool =  (oldState == AS_PLAYING);
```

this will save one extra assignment operation. when `myBool` is true before `if`

Comment: And that's not the only problem with the second statement, as it will not set `myBool` to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

`myBool = myBoolA || ( oldState == AS_PLAYING );`   //code #1
 seems to be correct version.

Your version is not equivalent to this. How? See

if `myBoolA`  is true and `( oldState == AS_PLAYING )` is false. `myBool` will still be true, but in your version, it will not be set.

**After EDIT**

```
if( oldState != AS_PLAYING )  myBool = false;    //code #2 more readable IMO
```

This will be fine only if, `myBool` is initialized with `true`.

Comment: Your after edit is wrong. If `myBool` is previously true, it would become `false`, which doesn't satisfy `myBool = myBool || (oldState == AS_PLAYING);`.

Comment: I don't remember why i said that, since there are so many edits since the actual question asked. I answered considering myBool and myBoolA as two different bool.